# Has anyone ever noticed weird numbers after completion of "mvn clean install"?

Tags: java, maven

My project is a maven project and so I run `mvn clean install` all the time. Recently, I noticed in the git bash that this command leaves some numbers in the end after successful completion.

Also, it sometimes makes my git bash window small and starts putting logs over logs. The logs which are under the other logs can't be accessed and in the end, I get number like below:

```
63;1;2;4;6;9;15;22;29c63;1;2;4;6;9;15;22;29c
63;1;2;4;6;9;15;22;29c
```

Project has other resources like activeMQ, email-functionality, etc and I get that it could be because of some resource not closed or could be some dependency issue.

But, still would be helpful if someone also has seen this and can point me in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-bash:

> Git Bash is an application for Microsoft Windows environments which provides an emulation layer for a Git command line experience.

That's the likely source of your problem. You'd be better off enabling the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and using a real terminal session, rather than an emulator.